# Use N patterns in str_replace in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Given I have `N` different patterns I want `str_replace` to check each pattern:

```
pat_list <- pattern1|pattern2| ......|patternN

str_replace(string, pattern = pat_list)
```

For example here are my patterns:

```
[1] "123-5"   "123-05"  "123-1"   "39-33"   "05"      "44-078"  "31-6"    "972-11"  "45-"     "33-7"    "49-17"   "20-12"   "123-"    "User_52" "44-79"   "33-6"   
[17] "44-75"   "358-4"   "43-699"  NA        ""
```

Now how do I "tell" `str_replace` to use a list of patterns?

Comment: You need `replace` argument as well

Comment: What is your replacement or replacements?

Comment: @akrun let's say it's ""

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen let's say it's ""

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need is

```
patterns <- c("123-5", "123-05", "123-1")
str_replace_all("123123-50123-0533", paste(patterns, collapse = "|"), "")
# [1] "123033"
```

Comment: @SteveS, does this answer your question?